# How do I find which user installed a package in linux?

Tags: linux, package

Is there a way to find out which user installed a package in linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually packets are installed by the superuser (`root`) account.

In case users use `sudo` to install them, you can check `~/.bash_history` for each user tu inspect who issued the `$ sudo apt-get install PACKAGE` (in case you're using `apt-get`).